# Insufficient arguments calculating raster zonal statistics

Tags: python, gdal

I found an useful python-GDAL example for calculating zonal statistics of a raster using polygons from a shapefile in the web.

At the end I get this error message:

> [ ERROR ] you must supply two arguments: input-zone-shapefile-name.shp
> input-value-raster-name.tif  An exception has occurred, use %tb to see
> the full traceback.
>
> SystemExit: 1

here is the code

```
import gdal, ogr, osr, numpy
import sys

def zonal_stats(feat, input_zone_polygon, input_value_raster):

    # Open data
        raster = gdal.Open("/home/giacomo/Desktop/prova_estrai/NDVI.tif")
        shp = ogr.Open("/home/giacomo/Desktop/prova_estrai/roi.shp")
        lyr = shp.GetLayer()
    
        # Get raster georeference info
        transform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
        xOrigin = transform[0]
        yOrigin = transform[3]
        pixelWidth = transform[1]
        pixelHeight = transform[5]
    
        # Reproject vector geometry to same projection as raster
        sourceSR = lyr.GetSpatialRef()
        targetSR = osr.SpatialReference()
        targetSR.ImportFromWkt(raster.GetProjectionRef())
        coordTrans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(sourceSR,targetSR)
        feat = lyr.GetNextFeature()
        geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
        geom.Transform(coordTrans)
    
        # Get extent of feat
        geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
        if (geom.GetGeometryName() == 'MULTIPOLYGON'):
            count = 0
            pointsX = []; pointsY = []
            for polygon in geom:
                geomInner = geom.GetGeometryRef(count)
                ring = geomInner.GetGeometryRef(0)
                numpoints = ring.GetPointCount()
                for p in range(numpoints):
                        lon, lat, z = ring.GetPoint(p)
                        pointsX.append(lon)
                        pointsY.append(lat)
                count += 1
        elif (geom.GetGeometryName() == 'POLYGON'):
            ring = geom.GetGeometryRef(0)
            numpoints = ring.GetPointCount()
            pointsX = []; pointsY = []
            for p in range(numpoints):
                    lon, lat, z = ring.GetPoint(p)
                    pointsX.append(lon)
                    pointsY.append(lat)
    
        else:
            sys.exit("ERROR: Geometry needs to be either Polygon or Multipolygon")
    
        xmin = min(pointsX)
        xmax = max(pointsX)
        ymin = min(pointsY)
        ymax = max(pointsY)
    
        # Specify offset and rows and columns to read
        xoff = int((xmin - xOrigin)/pixelWidth)
        yoff = int((yOrigin - ymax)/pixelWidth)
        xcount = int((xmax - xmin)/pixelWidth)+1
        ycount = int((ymax - ymin)/pixelWidth)+1
    
        # Create memory target raster
        target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', xcount, ycount, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
        target_ds.SetGeoTransform((
            xmin, pixelWidth, 0,
            ymax, 0, pixelHeight,
        ))
    
        # Create for target raster the same projection as for the value raster
        raster_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
        raster_srs.ImportFromWkt(raster.GetProjectionRef())
        target_ds.SetProjection(raster_srs.ExportToWkt())
    
        # Rasterize zone polygon to raster
        gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], lyr, burn_values=[1])
    
        # Read raster as arrays
        banddataraster = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
        dataraster = banddataraster.ReadAsArray(xoff, yoff, xcount, ycount).astype(numpy.float)
    
        bandmask = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
        datamask = bandmask.ReadAsArray(0, 0, xcount, ycount).astype(numpy.float)
    
        # Mask zone of raster
        zoneraster = numpy.ma.masked_array(dataraster,  numpy.logical_not(datamask))
    
        # Calculate statistics of zonal raster
        return numpy.average(zoneraster),numpy.mean(zoneraster),numpy.median(zoneraster),numpy.std(zoneraster),numpy.var(zoneraster)
    
    
    def loop_zonal_stats(input_zone_polygon, input_value_raster):
    
        shp = ogr.Open(input_zone_polygon)
        lyr = shp.GetLayer()
        featList = range(lyr.GetFeatureCount())
        statDict = {}
    
        for FID in featList:
            feat = lyr.GetFeature(FID)
            meanValue = zonal_stats(feat, input_zone_polygon, input_value_raster)
            statDict[FID] = meanValue
        return statDict
    
    def main(input_zone_polygon, input_value_raster):
        return loop_zonal_stats(input_zone_polygon, input_value_raster)
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    
        #
        # Returns for each feature a dictionary item (FID) with the statistical values in the following order: Average, Mean, Medain, Standard Deviation, Variance
        #
        # example run : $ python grid.py <full-path><output-shapefile-name>.shp xmin xmax ymin ymax gridHeight gridWidth
        #
    
        if len( sys.argv ) != 3:
            print ("[ ERROR ] you must supply two arguments: input-zone-shapefile-name.shp input-value-raster-name.tif ")
            sys.exit( 1 )
        print ('Returns for each feature a dictionary item (FID) with the statistical values in the following order: Average, Mean, Medain, Standard Deviation, Variance')
        print (main( sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2] ))
```

Comment: It looks like you don't give the script enough (or too many)  arguments at the command line. Can you specify how you run the script?

Comment: Of course. To run the script I just press F5 in in Spyder. Thank you